# what's the difference between "import keras" and "import tensorflow.keras"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I was wondering, what's the difference between importing keras from tensorflow using `import tensorflow.keras` or just pip installing keras alone and importing it using `import keras` as both seemed to work nicely so far, the only difference I noticed is that i get `Using TensorFlow backend.` in the command line every time I execute the one using keras.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Tensorflow.keras` is an version of Keras API implemented specifically for use with Tensorflow. It is a part of Tensorflow repo and from TF version 2.0 will become main high level API replacing `tf.layers` and `slim`.

The only reason to use standalone keras is to maintain framework-agnostic code, i.e. use it with another backend.