# Possible workaround to use LayerNormalization in Keras Sequential model

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I have a problem applying `LayerNormalization` in `keras` Sequential model in the following code:

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import keras
import tensorflow as tf

def create_classifier(dim):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu', input_dim=dim, trainable=True))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.LayerNormalization())
    model.add(Dense(int(neurons / 2), activation='relu', trainable=True))
    model.add(Dense(neurons, activation='relu',  trainable=True))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid', trainable=True))
    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=[keras.metrics.Recall()])
    model.summary()
    return model
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: The added layer must be an instance of class Layer. Found: <tensorflow.python.keras.layers.normalization.LayerNormalization object at 0x123b1ff90>
```

I wonder why it is not acceptable to mix up between `keras` and `tensorflow` (I have `keras 2.3.1` and `tensorflow 2.2.0`). Is there a workaround for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workaround is to change

```
from keras import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
```

into

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55178699/6561516) provides a good explanation of why that is.