# AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Adam'

Tags: python-3.8

When i am using "optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)" i am getting this error
"AttributeError: module 'keras.optimizers' has no attribute 'Adam". I am using python3.8 keras 2.6 and backend tensorflow 1.13.2 for running the program. Please help to resolve !

Answer (score 30):

Use `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)` instead of `keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)`

Comment: Awesome, this works. But follow-up question: What is the difference between the modules `keras` and `tensorflow.keras`?

Comment: tensorflow.keras is the adopted version of keras by tensorflow. You can read more here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63517100/4584901

Answer (score 14):

As per the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/optimizers/) , try to import `keras` into your code like this,

```
>>> from tensorflow import keras
```

This has helped me as well.

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you've imported tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

Then use

```
tf.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate)
```

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to solve your problem as you are using keras 2.6 and tensorflow too:

- use (from keras.optimizer_v2.adam import Adam as Adam) but go through the function documentation once to specify your learning rate and beta values
- you can also use (Adam = keras.optimizers.Adam).
- (import tensorflow as tf) then (Adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam)

Use the form that is useful for the environment you set

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using Keras directly. Instead of giving as from keras.distribute import  —> give as from tensorflow.keras.distribute import

Hope this would help you.. It is working for me.